# Dropping foreign keys in Laravel causes an error

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration

After creating and using my database within my laravel application I have realized I initially put foreign keys on the wrong tables. I have a tables called **Places**, **Prices** and **Websites** that I want to change their columns and keys in. At the moment **Places** is referenced in both **Prices** and **Websites** but I want to change it so that **Prices** and **Websites** are both referenced in **Places**.

[ERD of what my tables look like currently vs what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZSas.png)

In order to do this I need to drop both the keys and columns from **Prices** and **Websites** and add two new columns to **Places**. For the life of me I cannot get the migration to drop the columns and foreign keys to successfully migrate.

This is the error that comes up when I try to migrate

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP FOREIGN KEY `prices_placeid_foreign`; check that it exists (SQL: alter table `prices` drop foreign key `prices_placeid_foreign`)
```

This is my migration

```
Schema::table('prices', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign(['placeid']);
            $table->dropColumn('placeid');
        });
```

And this is the Prices structure

```
Schema::create('prices', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id()->autoIncrement(); //PK
            $table->integer('low');
            $table->integer('high');

            $table->foreignId('placeid')->constrained('places')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

Some of the things I've tried

```
$table->dropForeign('prices_placeid_foreign');
```

```
$table->dropColumn(['placeid']);
```

According to my table structure the foreign key name is 'prices_placeid_foreign'

[Table Structure in PhpMyAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55evi.png)

EDIT: The migration where the Places table is created has already run, I am trying to do a new migration that drop the column and the key and that is what is returning the error

**Please help!!!**

Comment: The message seems clear, the FK doesn't exists, remove the line `dropForeign` in the rollback method and try again

Comment: I've tried the migrations you've shared (plus a simple `places` migration) on a fresh Laravel app and I can't reproduce this issue. You might want double check your tables in case there's anything off

Comment: @apokryfos Sorry if not made clear but the migration where the places table is created has already run. I am now trying to undo that by adding a new migration that drops the columns and foreign key. So its the new migration that returns the error

Comment: Yes, I understand that part. I did that as well but cannot reproduce the issue. Double-check that the indexed field is correctly marked as a foreign key as well

Comment: I think that may be it. I deleted the Prices table in PhpMyAdmin and rollback my migrations to create it again. When I migrated it returned an error for the Prices table. I will keep working on it- thanks for making me look in the right direction!